# Text Editor with FTP

Tags: ftp, text-editor, bluefish

I'm new to Ubuntu. Is there a text editor with built in FTP out there that anyone can recommend to me? I am trying to use Bluefish right now.

Comment: You can use an FTP client like FileZilla that has the support of editing/viewing remote files with you local editor. Saved modification will then be uploaded to the server through FTP of course.

Comment: Is there anything that is like PSPad on Windows where it is already integrated into the Text Editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gedit will see any saved bookmarks you make in Nautilus. So in Nautilus you can File>Connect to Server   and then Bookmark that location once it opens.

Gedit will see those bookmarks and can open right to your files. You can also install some additional plugins and options for Gedit to show line numbers, snippets and find/replace.

Works great.